# What is the definition of linear kernel?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]
I don't understand what does it mean  "linear kernel".
As far as I understand any  integrable function K(t,s) could suit this theorem.
Could someone explain what is the definition of linear kernel and why we need this condition here.

Comment: Have you tried looking up "kernel" or "linear kernel" in the index of the text?

Comment: yes, It is the only place that it appears.

Comment: "kernel" is just how it is used. Most case, non negative, or integrable. Sometimes integrate to 1, sometimes smooth. Just google integral kernel

Comment: My guess: you're probably right that $K$ can be any integrable function, and it is common to refer to that function as *"the linear kernel of the system"*.